# segmentation fault (can solve with initialization list, can't with copy constructor)

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, initializer-list

I'm having segmentation fault error in my code:

```cpp
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

#include "game.hpp"
#include "map.hpp"
#include "button.hpp"


class Game {
private:
   Map map;
   Button play_button;
   Button menu_button;
   std::string state = "menu";
public:
    Game(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        map.setBlockWidth(window);

        sf::Vector2u window_size = window.getSize();
        int button_width = window_size.x / 4;
        int button_height = window_size.y / 10;

        play_button = Button(sf::Vector2f(button_width, button_height), sf::Vector2f((window_size.x / 2) - (button_width / 2), (window_size.y / 2) - (button_height / 2)), [this]() {state = "game";}, "PLAY");
        menu_button = Button(sf::Vector2f(window_size.x / 10, window_size.y / 20), sf::Vector2f(10, 10), [this]() {state = "menu";}, "MENU");
    }

    ~Game() {}
    
    void update(sf::RenderWindow &window, bool LMB_pressed) {
        if (state == "menu") {
            if (LMB_pressed) {
                play_button.detectOnClick(window);
            }

            renderMenu(window);
        } else if (state == "game") {
            if (LMB_pressed) {
                menu_button.detectOnClick(window);
            }

            map.update(window);
            renderInterface(window);
        }
    }

    void renderMenu(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        window.draw(play_button);
    }

    void renderInterface(sf::RenderWindow &window) {
        window.draw(menu_button);
    }
};
```

I can fix this problem by moving code below from constructor to update method, but It's horrible solution.

```cpp
sf::Vector2u window_size = window.getSize();
        int button_width = window_size.x / 4;
        int button_height = window_size.y / 10;

        play_button = Button(sf::Vector2f(button_width, button_height), sf::Vector2f((window_size.x / 2) - (button_width / 2), (window_size.y / 2) - (button_height / 2)), [this]() {state = "game";}, "PLAY");
        menu_button = Button(sf::Vector2f(window_size.x / 10, window_size.y / 20), sf::Vector2f(10, 10), [this]() {state = "menu";}, "MENU");
```

The other solution is using initialization list:

```cpp
Game(sf::RenderWindow &window) : play_button(sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Vector2f(0, 0), [this]() {state = "game";}, "PLAY"),
                                     menu_button(sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Vector2f(0, 0), [this]() {state = "menu";}, "MENU") {
        map.setBlockWidth(window);

        sf::Vector2u window_size = window.getSize();
        int button_width = window_size.x / 4;
        int button_height = window_size.y / 10;

        play_button.setPosition(sf::Vector2f((window_size.x / 2) - (button_width / 2), (window_size.y / 2) - (button_height / 2)));
        play_button.setSize(sf::Vector2f(button_width, button_height));

        menu_button.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));
        menu_button.setSize(sf::Vector2f(window_size.x / 10, window_size.y / 20));
    }
```

The problem with this is I'm required to write additional setXXX methods

Ideally I would like to use copy constructor (I think it might work and be the smartest idea), but I can't make it work with compiler auto generated constructor.

Problem seems to be with creating Button objects as member variable, and then assigning button object created in constructor to that member variable. It looks like after leaving constructor objects are deleted.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how it can help me diagnose problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Your `Button` copy-constructor (which you have forgotten to declare in the class) doesn't do anything that the default compiler-generated copy-constructor won't do.

Comment: Also note that assignment doesn't use the copy-constructor, it's invoking the assignment operator function `operator=`.

Comment: On what line does the segmentation fault happen?

Comment: @JaMiT in the update method, when detecting onClickEvent

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes, I know that compiler generates it's own copy constructor and assignment operator.

Comment: You should rely on that then.

Comment: @PaulSanders OK, still not working

Comment: Run it under the debugger and get a stack trace

Comment: `valgrind` will tell you what exactly is wrong with your memory accesses, on which line and under what stack trace. Make sure you give it a `-g`-compiled binary to get as many details as possible.

Comment: @DR4NKR1D3R *"in the update method, when detecting onClickEvent"* -- **First,** this information should be in the question. **Second,** this information is inadequate. My first instinct was to do a "find in page" for "onClickEvent" and came up empty. When I searched for "update" instead, I found **two** calls to `detectOnClick`. **Third,** you should simplify your code so the line is easier to find. The goal of your [mre] should be to demonstrate the seg fault, not to do fancy button switching. Maybe call `play_button.detectOnClick(window);` immediately after setting `play_button`?

Comment: *"Problem seems to be with creating Button objects [...]"* -- This makes the (current) lack  of a definition of the `Button` class a significant gap in your question.